# how to clone heroku git repository with PuTTY

Tags: git, heroku, putty

**What I am trying to do ?**

I am trying to clone my heroku git repository with [PuTTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY):

```
git clone https://git.heroku.com/projectname.git
```

**What is the problem ?**

When I clone the heroku repository I get prompted for username and password which I enter as heroku doc says it in [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git#http-git-authentication) ( Ignoring the username and enter your account API key as your password ). But that gives me this error:

```
remote: ! WARNING:
remote: ! Do not authenticate with username and password using git.
remote: ! Run `heroku login` to update your credentials, then retry the git command.
remote: ! See documentation for details: 
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.heroku.com/projectname.git/'
```

I also tried to generate SSH key in heroku and provide that key as my password but still getting the same error.

This is all new to me so I am having hard time with it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Heroku has this functionality built into the CLI. You can simply use `heroku git:clone` which will automatically use the creds in your `.netrc`.